# Pandas Save the results of groupby operation as new column in the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to set the result of

```
df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum())
```

as the column `c2` of my dataframe.

So I do this:

```
df['c2'] = pd.to_numeric(df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum()).astype(float)
```

Thus

```
pd.to_numeric(df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum()).astype(float)
```

has type float, and so `df['c2']` should also have type float.

However, when I tried to print the column of my dataframe `df['c2']` all values are `NaN`.

How can I solve this?

---

EDIT 1:

[My code is here](https://files.fm/u/9z82t6wk)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: thank you ! when i try to print my column it is all at NAN!

Comment: Please proofread and properly format your questions. Please also provide all the information that is neccessary to understand your problem, e.g. a sample of your data.

Comment: my column is having NAN as value.. i can't solve it

Comment: i don't know how to convert NAN it to int or to float. I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work

Comment: do you have NaN in the column initially ? Do you want to get the sum but there are some NaNs in the column ?

Comment: the result of my `print(df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum())` is integers .But when i try to set it to my dataframe column it became NAN. hope that it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, after this part:

```
import numpy as np
d_copy = d.copy()
```

### Do this:

```
d_copy['counts2'] = d_copy.groupby(['region'])['counts'].transform('count')
```

**Results**:
[image]

Comment: it calculates the sum.. but when i try to put the result in a column of my dataframe it shows NAN

Comment: when you type this `df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum())` do you have NaNs in the result?

Comment: no i have integers. 1 ,5,6

Comment: it shows NAN only when i do this `df['c2'] = pd.to_numeric(df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum())`

Comment: try this:  `df['c2'] = pd.to_numeric(df.groupby(['région'])['counts'].sum(), downcast='float')`

Comment: It is always NAN :(

Comment: can you add some data ? then I can help you solve this

Comment: yes of course!! but didn't know how to add picture in comment

Comment: no. edit your original post and then upload the data (give a link to the data).

Comment: i did it .. hope that it is clear now

Comment: can you add a link to be able to download the data and try ? With screenshots is difficult

Comment: ok can you give me you email?? where i can send my code

Comment: use this add post the link: https://files.fm/

Comment: i uploaded the file

Comment: try this link https://files.fm/u/9z82t6wk

Comment: i will have a look now and I will let you know

Comment: thank you so much for your help^^

Comment: I found the problem. The `d_copy` has 86 rows. But when you do: `d_copy.groupby(['region'])['counts'].sum()` this is a result with `41` rows because you have grouped. So you are trying to put a vector of 41 rows in a DataFrame that has 86. This creates the NaNs

Comment: thank you but all the 86 are in NAN

Comment: Yes because you are trying to store the results of `d_copy.groupby(['region'])['counts'].sum()` that has 41 elements, in the original dataframe that has 86 elements. What exactly do you want to do? You have the sum grouped by region.

Comment: i want to sum count per "région" and put it in a nex column c2

Comment: okay. I solved it. I am going to change my answer now

Comment: see my new answer. It does what you want. Please upvote & accept my answer if it helps

Comment: thank you so much it is so helpful for me

Comment: parfait. de rien !